# how to find .txt files in a directory, and write in it in python?

Tags: python, txt

I want to find a .txt file in the directory, and write some text in it. If there are many .txt files, i want to write the same text in all of them. how to do that?
python language i need it. Is there any way i can do this ?

```
for file in os.listdir("/Users/coder/Desktop/Sample Folder"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        print(os.path.join("/Users/coder/Desktop/Sample Folder", file))

x = open(file, "r+")
x.write("This file is a .txt file")
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can shift the lines in  the for loop.

```
for file in os.listdir("/Users/coder/Desktop/Sample Folder"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):

        with open(os.path.join("/Users/coder/Desktop/Sample Folder", file),"a+") as file:
            file.write("This file is a .txt file")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enter data like this,

```
import glob
import os
path = 'E:\Path'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
   with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'a') as f:
       f.write("Type the required information")
```

Change the `path` to the folder you are changing the text of

Comment: `glob` is case sensitive.